# Get DateTime for the nth Sunday after today

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, week-number

I'm using the following to get the current week number:

```
var weekNo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.UtcNow,
                                                  CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek,
                                                  DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

And I want to return the `DateTime` representing the first day of the nth week after today.

e.g. when n = 2, I would want the `DateTime` representing the Sunday after next.

Is there a way I can do this in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
DateTime sundayInFuture = DateTime.Today.AddDays((n - 1) * 7 + (7 - (int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek));
```

That should work (though I've not got access to anything to test it!).

Edit: Thanks to the comments.

Comment: @anishMarokey - if you post a comment like this, at least explain the why, or what error you are getting.

Comment: @anishMarokey: Why not? What did I miss?

Comment: I had to cast DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek to int, but otherwise this works. - Thanks.

Comment: @Andy: No probs. I'll update my answer with the final solution

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
int n = 2;
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
int daysToNextSunday = (7 - today.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Sunday) ;
DateTime nthSunday = today.AddDays((n - 1) * 7 + daysToNextSunday);
```

Comment: DayOfWeek.Sunday = 0, so you can simplify things slightly by ignoring that.

Comment: @Jackson: Yes - I didn't want to make this assumption though, it's easier for me to parse by having it there explicitly

Comment: Fair enough - it also makes it easier to convert to a different day of the week.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't make it easier to convert. This code works because sunday == 0, with a different day daysToNext can become negative effectively making it daysToPrevious...

Answer (score 1):

Could you add the number of days from now until Sunday, and then add (n-1)*7 more days?

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that **Calendar.GetWeekOfYear** is not **ISO 8601** conform.

Here a sample Using the **Week** class of the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx):

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public DateTime GetStartOfWeek( DateTime moment, int offset )
{
  return new Week( new Week( moment ).WeekOfYear + Math.Abs( offset ) ).FirstDayOfWeek;
} // GetStartOfWeek
```